# Run a program in a ForEach loop

Tags: powershell, foreach, pipeline

I'm trying to get this simple PowerShell script working, but I think something is fundamentally wrong. ;-)

```
ls | ForEach { "C:\Working\tools\custom-tool.exe" $_ }
```

I basically want to get files in a directory, and pass them one by one as arguments to the custom tool.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
ls | %{C:\Working\tools\custom-tool.exe $_}
```

As each object comes down the pipeline the tool will be run against it.  Putting quotes around the command string causes it to be... a string!  The local variable "$_" it then likely doesn't know what to do with so pukes with an error.

Answer (score 46):

If you still need quotes around the command path (say, if you've got spaces), just do it like this:

```
ls | % { &"C:\Working\tools\custom-tool.exe" $_.FullName }
```

Notice the use of & before the string to force PowerShell to interpret it as a command and not a string.

Comment: And if flags are needed, they can be added after the end; `ls | % { &"C:\Working\tools\custom-tool.exe" $_.FullName --flag --flag2=47}`

Comment: I found out.  It's an alias for `ForEach-Object`.  You can see current aliases at the powershell prompt by typing `get-alias`

Answer (score 6):

I'm betting your tool needs the full path.  The $_ is each file object that comes through the pipeline.  You likely need to use an expression like this:

```
ls | %{C:\Working\tools\custom-tool.exe $_.fullname}
```

Answer (score 3):

Both Jeffrery Hicks and slipsec are correct.  Yank the double quotes off.

$_ or $_.fullname worked in my test script (below).  YMMV with your custom-tool.

```
gci | % { c:\windows\notepad.exe $_.fullname }
```

or

```
gci | % { c:\windows\notepad.exe $_ }
```