# How do I reference variables when executing a shell command in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'm a newbie to PowerShell.  What's wrong with my script below?  It's not wanting to emit the value of `$config`.  However, when I wrap that command in double quotes, everything looks okay.

```
param($config, $logfolder)

# Must run log analysis in chronological order.
ls $logfolder | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | % {
    perl D:\Websites\_awstats\wwwroot\cgi-bin\awstats.pl -LogFile="$($_.FullName)" -config=$config update
}

# Execute with - .\regen-logs.ps1 webgenesis "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC5"
# Returns for each file - Error: Couldn't open config file "awstats.config.conf" nor "awstats.conf" after searching in path "D:\Websites\_awstats\wwwroot\cgi-bin,/etc/awstats,/usr/local/etc/awstats,/etc,/etc/opt/awstats": No such file or directory
```

As-is, what gets emitted and executed seems to have "-config=$config" passed as an argument.  At least, that's my best guess.  I don't know if $_ is working correctly either.

If I put quotes around the perl command like so, I get the command I do want to execute.

```
ls $logfolder | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | % {
    "perl D:\Websites\_awstats\wwwroot\cgi-bin\awstats.pl -LogFile=`"$($_.FullName)`" -config=$config update"
}

# Outputs for each log file something like - perl D:\Websites\_awstats\wwwroot\cgi-bin\awstats.pl -LogFile="C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC5\u_ex110602.log" -config=webgenesis update
```

Comment: What do you mean with "when I wrap that command in double quotes"? Can you show the working version?

Comment: What error messages are you receiving ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If putting quotes around it produces the correct commandline, one way to execute the contents of a string is with `Invoke-Expression` (alias `iex`):

```
$v = "myexe -myarg1 -myarg2=$someVar"
iex $v
```

Answer (score 1):

Put double quotes around `"-config=$config"`.  Without this, PowerShell will interpret `-config=$config` as one string argument that just happens to contain a `$` sign in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to start your perl command out with `&` so that PowerShell interprets things as a command and not a string.

```
& perl D:\Websites\_awstats\wwwroot\cgi-bin\awstats.pl -LogFile=`"$($_.FullName)`" -config=$config update
```

Also, see: [Run a program in a foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/181036/4916)

Comment: The term 'perl D:\Websites\_awstats\wwwroot\cgi-bin\awstats.pl -LogFile="D:\Websites\_awstats\update-awstats.bat" -config= update' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling o f the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: @Stuart-Branham Sorry about that. I messed up the quoting. Thinking this should work.

Comment: The call operator "&" can't handle compound expressions like that. See Joel's answer.